# API to access spreadsheets of a user in office 365

Tags: outlook, office365

Is there an api to access spreadsheets of logged in user for office 365. During my quest what I found was only for mail, calendar, contacts.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When we create an spreadsheet using Excel online using Office 365 account, this file was store on the OneDrive for business. And we can use OneDrive API to get the files store on the OneDrive or OneDrive for business.

Here is an helpful link for your reference:

https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm